# Center text in Tikz node with different fonts

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

I am trying to create a title page for a book. The first letter of the title is written with the font Eileen Caps Black and the rest with `\normalfont`. This title is to be centered above an ornament from the `pgfornament` package.

However, there is some padding around the letter of the font Eileen Caps Black and the title is being shifted to the right side. It can be shifted to the left manually by adding `\hspace{}` after the title but this value needs to be adapted for each capitalized letter.

Can the title be automatically centered above the ornament?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfornament} % Vectorian Ornaments

\input EileenBl.fd% To load the font
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{EileenBl}{xl}{n}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    
    % Length title ornament
    \newcommand{\titleornamentlength}{1.5}
    
    % To create capitalized titles with enluminure
    \newcommand{\enluminure}[2]{\initfamily\fontsize{35mm}{35mm}\selectfont#1\normalfont\Huge#2}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}]
        
        % Draw title ornament
        \node[anchor=west, xshift= -\titleornamentlength cm] (TSW) {};
        \node[anchor=east, xshift= +\titleornamentlength cm] (TSE) {};
        \pgfornamentline{TSW}{TSE}{1}{87}
        
        % Create node at ornament center
        \node[xshift= \titleornamentlength cm] at (TSW.center) (TSC) {};
        
        % Draw title
        \node[anchor=south, align=center, yshift= 0.5 cm] at (TSC.center){\enluminure{T}{his is a title}};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm afraid without doing this manually for every letter there is really not much that can be done here. TeX doesn't know the shape of the glyphs you put in your output, it only knows the size of the boxes. If the padding around the letters of that font isn't uniform for every glyph then there isn't much hope for you. If the padding is uniform you could use `\kern-0.05em` (or something like that) to negate that padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @Skillmon comment, I managed to write a solution comining `\kern` and `\hspace{}`, as shown in the MWE below.

I drew the node in red and it is now centered nicely above the ornament with the capitalized letter reaching the edge of the node. I checked each letter of the alphabet: details of a few letter are outside the node drawing but it is hardly visible without the node as a reference. It no longer needs to be manually adapted.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfornament} % Vectorian Ornaments

% To load the font
\input EileenBl.fd% Enluminure ont
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{EileenBl}{xl}{n}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    
    % Length title ornament
    \newcommand{\titleornamentlength}{1.5}
    
    % To create capitalized titles with enluminure
    \newcommand{\enluminure}[2]{\hspace{0.2cm}\initfamily\fontsize{35mm}{35mm}\selectfont\kern-0.12em#1\normalfont\Huge#2}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}]
        
        % Draw title ornament
        \node[anchor=west, xshift= -\titleornamentlength cm] (TSW) {};
        \node[anchor=east, xshift= +\titleornamentlength cm] (TSE) {};
        \pgfornamentline{TSW}{TSE}{1}{87}
        
        % Create node at ornament center
        \node[xshift= \titleornamentlength cm] at (TSW.center) (TSC) {};
        
        % Draw title
        \node[draw=red, anchor=south, align=center, yshift= 0.5 cm] at (TSC.center){\enluminure{T}{his is a title}};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```